# Angular CDK Virtual scroll not selecting all columns in matselect at once large dataset

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar

I have a mat-select in angular like this with virtual scroll.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectControl" multiple [value]="selected" (openedChange)="openChange($event)">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="5" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400" [style.height.px]=5*48>
    <button (click)="selectAll()">Select All</button>
    <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
    <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-select>
```

.ts file:

```
@ViewChildren(MatOption)
options: QueryList<MatOption>;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.options.changes.subscribe(() => {
    let needUpdate = false;

    this.options.forEach((option) => {
      const selected = this.selected.includes(option.value);
       if (selected && !option.selected) {
        option.select();
        needUpdate = true;
      } else if (!selected && option.selected) {
        option.deselect();
        needUpdate = true;
      }
    });
    if (needUpdate) {
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
  });
}

onSelectionChange(change): void {
  if (!change.isUserInput) {
    return;
  }

  const value = change.source.value;
  const idx = this.selected.indexOf(change.source.value);

  if (idx > -1) {
    this.selected.splice(idx, 1)
  } else {
    this.selected.push(value);
  }
}
```

with a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufabzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link.

If I click Select All and scroll faster, all the element doesnt get selected like they take time to get selected. Is there any way to improve the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to listen to the scrolled `Observable` on the [`ScrollDispatcher`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#ScrollDispatcher):

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.sd.scrolled().pipe(
      filter((scrollable) => this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort === scrollable)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      let needUpdate = false;

      this.options.forEach((option) => {
        const selected = this.selected.includes(option.value);

        if (selected && !option.selected) {
          option.select();
          needUpdate = true;
        } else if (!selected && option.selected) {
          option.deselect();
          needUpdate = true;
        }
      });

      if (needUpdate) {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }
```

You could potentially debounce the event, so that it doesn't get fired too much. I've updated the stackblitz with this solution

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufabzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hey @PierreDuc, thanks for your answer. I am going through the same problem. Your solution works a lot but still there a problem noticed- Click Select All, Unselect top two elements, Again click on Select All and it doesnt work.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. they are really helpful. I am facing a little issues, can we start a chat here on stackoverflow

Comment: any suggestion on select all - unselect 2 and then select all again?

Comment: @Gauravsa Sure, you need to do `this.selected = [ ...this.toppingList];` in the `selectAll` to copy the toppingList, otherwise the `toppingList` array itself gets changed while doing selections

Comment: @JameerKhan See my comment above :)